# dbt how to use is_incremental macro inside run_query

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dbt

i have a table where one of the columns is complex nested JSON data structure that i will need to unravel into a tabular format. Something like `{"abc": ["123"], "def": [456]}`. The keys are dynamically generated and is different for each record hence I am using Jinja to help extract the key values like

input row:

| last_modified | id | nested_json |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 00:01:11 | qwerty | {"abc": ["123"], "def": [456]} |

expected output:

| last_modified | id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 00:01:11 | qwerty | abc | 123 |
| 2024-01-01 00:01:11 | qwerty | def | 456 |

Due to the nature of the nested JSON being nested, I have run into issues where dbt generates a SQL query that exceeds the maximum size limit. I tried using the `incremental` approach but I am manually running delete statements in my model and would like to replace it with dbt's `is_incremental` macro but I am stumped on how/where to put it in my current `model.sql` file shown below:

```
{{ config(
    materialized='incremental',
    pre_hook={'sql': 'delete from dbt.target_table where last_modified >= (select max(last_modified) from dbt.target_table)'}
    ) 
}}

{# /*grab the latest modified records in the source table*/ #}
{% set cte = run_query("select last_modified, id, nested_json
                        from source_table
                        where is_valid_json(nested_json) and
                            last_modified >= (select max(last_modified)
                                                from dbt.target_table)
                        order by last_modified, aid") %}
{% if execute %}
{% set results_list = cte.rows %}
{% else %}
{% set results_list = [] %}
{% endif %}

{# /*unnesting JSON into tabular format*/ #}
with stg as (
    {% for row in results_list %}
        {% if not loop.first %}
        union
        {% endif %}
        select
        
        {# /* create union statements to make each key/value
            * pair its own record in the target table
            */ #}
        {% set json_dict = fromjson(row[2]) %}
            {% for key, value in json_dict.items() %}
                {% set value = value|replace("'", '"') %}
                '{{ row[0] }}' as last_modified,
                {{ row[1] }} as id,
                '{{ key }}' as key,
                '{{ value }}' as value
                {% if not loop.last %}union select{% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
)


select cast(a.last_modified as timestamptz) as last_modified
    , a.id
    , a.key
    , json_extract_array_element_text(value, b.num) as value
from stg as a
cross join some.other_table as b
where b.num < json_array_length(a.value)
```

thanks in advance!